# How calculate the number of files which can be passed as arguments to some command for batch processing?

Tags: linux, bash, ulimit

For example, I have directory with multiple files created by this way:

```
touch files/{1..10231}_file.txt
```

I want to move them into new directory `new_files_dir`.

The simplest way to do this is:

```
for filename in files/*; do
    mv "${filename}" -t "new_files_dir"
done
```

This script works for **10** seconds on my computer. It is slow. The slowness happens due execution of `mv` command for every file.

**###Edit start###**

I have understood, that in my example the simplest way will be just

```
mv files/* -t new_files_dir
```

or, if the "Argument list too long":

```
printf '%s\0' files/* | xargs -0 mv -t new_files_dir
```

but aforementioned case is a part of task. The whole task is in this question: [Moving large number of files into directories based on file names in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609437/109397).
So, the files must be moved into corresponding subdirectories, the correspondence of which is based on a number in the filename. This is the cause of `for` loop usage and other oddities in my code snippets.

**###Edit end###**

There is possibility to speedup this process by passing bunch of files to `mv` command instead of a single file, like this:

```
batch_num=1000

# Counting of files in the directory
shopt -s nullglob
file_list=(files/*)
file_num=${#file_list[@]}

# Every file's common part
suffix='_file.txt'

for((from = 1, to = batch_num; from <= file_num; from += batch_num, to += batch_num)); do
    if ((to > file_num)); then
        to="$file_num"
    fi  

    # Generating filenames by `seq` command and passing them to `xargs`
    seq -f "files/%.f${suffix}" "$from" "$to" |
    xargs -n "${batch_num}" mv -t "new_files_dir"
done
```

In this case the script works for **0.2** seconds. So, the performance has increased by 50 times.

**But there is a problem:** at any moment the program can refuse to work due "Argument list too long", because I can't guarantee that the bunch of filenames length is less than max allowable length.

**My idea** is to calculate the `batch_num`:

```
batch_num = "max allowable length" / "longest filename length"
```

and then use this `batch_num` in `xargs`.

Thus, **the question:** How can max allowable length be calculated?

---

**I have done something:**

1. Overall length can be found by this way:

   ```
    $ getconf ARG_MAX
    2097152
   ```
2. The environment variables contributes into the argument size too, so probably they should be subtracted from `ARG_MAX`:

   ```
    $ env | wc -c
    3403
   ```
3. Made a method to determine the max number of files of equal sizes by trying different amount of files before the right value is found (binary search is used).

   ```
    function find_max_file_number {
        right=2000000
        left=1
        name=$1
        while ((left < right)); do
            mid=$(((left + right) / 2))

            if /bin/true $(yes "$name" | head -n "$mid") 2>/dev/null; then
                left=$((mid + 1))
            else
                right=$((mid - 1))
            fi
        done
        echo "Number of ${#name} byte(s) filenames:" $((mid - 1))
    }

    find_max_file_number A
    find_max_file_number AA
    find_max_file_number AAA
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
    Number of 1 byte(s) filenames: 209232
    Number of 2 byte(s) filenames: 190006
    Number of 3 byte(s) filenames: 174248
   ```

   But I can't understand the logic/relation behind these results yet.
4. Have tried values from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110301/109397) for calculation, but they didn't fit.
5. Wrote a **C** program to calculate the total size of passed arguments. The result of this program is close, but some non-counted bytes are left:

   ```
    $ ./program {1..91442}_file.txt

    arg strings size: 1360534
    number of pointers to strings 91443

    argv size:  1360534 + 91443 * 8 = 2092078
    envp size:  3935

    Overall (argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc)):  2092078 + 3935 + 4 = 2096017
    ARG_MAX: 2097152

    ARG_MAX - overall = 1135 # <--- Enough bytes are
                             # left, but no additional
                             # filenames are permitted.

    $ ./program {1..91443}_file.txt
    bash: ./program: Argument list too long
   ```

   **program.c**

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
        size_t chr_ptr_size = sizeof(argv[0]);
        // The arguments array total size calculation
        size_t arg_strings_size = 0;
        size_t str_len = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            str_len = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
            arg_strings_size += str_len;
    //      printf("%zu:\t%s\n\n", str_len, argv[i]);
        }

        size_t argv_size = arg_strings_size + argc * chr_ptr_size;
        printf( "arg strings size: %zu\n"
                "number of pointers to strings %i\n\n"
                "argv size:\t%zu + %i * %zu = %zu\n",
                 arg_strings_size,
                 argc,
                 arg_strings_size,
                 argc,
                 chr_ptr_size,
                 argv_size
            );

        // The enviroment variables array total size calculation
        size_t env_size = 0;
        for (char **env = envp; *env != 0; env++) {
          char *thisEnv = *env;
          env_size += strlen(thisEnv) + 1 + sizeof(thisEnv);
        }

        printf("envp size:\t%zu\n", env_size);

        size_t overall = argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc);

        printf( "\nOverall (argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc)):\t"
                "%zu + %zu + %zu = %zu\n",
                 argv_size,
                 env_size,
                 sizeof(argc),
                 overall);
        // Find ARG_MAX by system call
        long arg_max = sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX);

        printf("ARG_MAX: %li\n\n", arg_max);
        printf("ARG_MAX - overall = %li\n", arg_max - (long) overall);

        return 0;
    }
   ```

   I have asked a question about the correctness of this program on StackOverflow: [The maximum summarized size of argv, envp, argc (command line arguments) is always far from the ARG_MAX limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63959200/2913477).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CP: max source files number arguments for copy utility](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/110282)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a shell where `mv` is or can be made builtin, and you won't have the problem (which is a limitation of the `execve()` system call, so only with external commands). It will also not matter as much how many times you call `mv`.

`zsh`, `busybox sh`, `ksh93` (depending on how it was built) are some of those shells. With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

zmodload zsh/files # makes mv and a few other file manipulation commands builtin
batch=1000
files=(files/*(N))

for ((start = 1; start <= $#files; start += batch)) {
  (( end = start + batch - 1))
  mkdir -p ${start}_${end} || exit
  mv -- $files[start,end] ${start}_${end}/ || exit
}
```

The `execve()` E2BIG limit applies differently depending on the system (and version thereof), can depend on things like stacksize limit. It generally takes into account the size of each `argv[]` and `envp[]` strings (including the terminating NUL character), often the size of those arrays of pointers (and terminating NULL pointer) as well (so it depends both on the size and number of arguments). Beware that the shell can set some env vars at the last minute as well (like the `_` one that some shells set to the path of the commands being executed).

It could also depend on the type of executable (ELF, script, binfmt_misc). For instance, for scripts, `execve()` ends up doing a second `execve()` with a generally longer arg list (`["myscrip", "arg", NULL]` becomes `["/path/to/interpreter" or "myscript" depending on system, "-<option>" if any on the shebang, "myscript", "arg"]`).

Also beware that some commands end up executing other commands with the same list of args and possibly some extra env vars. For instance, `sudo cmd arg` runs `cmd arg` with `SUDO_COMMAND=/path/to/cmd arg` in its environment (doubling the space required to hold the list of arguments).

You may be able to come up with the right algorithm for your current Linux kernel version, with the current version of your shell and the specific command you want to execute, to maximise  the number of arguments you can pass to `execve()`, but that may no longer be valid of the next version of the kernel/shell/command. Better would be to take `xargs` approach and give enough slack to account for all those extra variations or use `xargs`.

GNU `xargs` has a `--show-limits` option that details how it handles it:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
$ uname -rs
Linux 5.7.0-3-amd64
$ xargs --show-limits < /dev/null
Your environment variables take up 3456 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091648
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2088192
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

You can see `ARG_MAX` is 2MiB in my case, `xargs` thinks it could use up to `2088192`, but chooses to limit itself to 128KiB.

Just as well as:

```
$ yes '""' | xargs -s 230000 | head -1 | wc -c
229995
$ yes '""' | strace -fe execve xargs -s 240000 | head -1 | wc -c
[...]
[pid 25598] execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "", "", "", ...], 0x7ffe2e742bf8 /* 47 vars */) = -1 E2BIG (Argument list too long)
[pid 25599] execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "", "", "", ...], 0x7ffe2e742bf8 /* 47 vars */) = 0
[...]
119997
```

It could not pass 239,995 empty arguments (with total string size of 239,995 bytes for the NUL delimiters, so fitting in that 240,000 buffer) so tried again with half as many. That's a small amount of data, but you have to consider that the pointer list for those strings is 8 times as big, and if we add up those, we get over 2MiB.

When I did this same kind of tests over 6 years ago in [that Q&A here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110301/22565) with Linux 3.11, I was getting a different behaviour which had already changed recently at the time, showing that the exercise of coming up with the right algorithm to maximise the number of arguments to pass is a bit pointless.

Here, with an average file path size of 32 bytes, with a 128KiB buffer, that's still 4096 filenames passed to `mv` and the cost of starting `mv` is alreadly becoming negligible compared to the cost of renaming/moving all those files.

For a less conservative buffer size (to pass to `xargs -s`) but that should still work for any arg list with past versions of Linux at least, you could do:

```
$ (env | wc; getconf ARG_MAX) | awk '
  {env = $1 * 8 + $3; getline; printf "%d\n", ($0 - env) / 9 - 4096}'
228499
```

Where we compute a high estimate of the space used by the environment (number of lines in `env` output should be at least as big as the number of `envp[]` pointers we passed to `env`, and we count 8 bytes for each of those, plus their size (including NULs which `env` replaced with NL)), substract that from `ARG_MAX` and divide by 9 to cover for the worst case scenario of a list of empty args and add 4KiB of slack.

Note that if you limit the stack size to 4MiB or below (with `limit stacksize 4M` in `zsh` for instance), that becomes *more* conservative than GNU `xargs`'s default buffer size (which remains 128K in my case and fails to pass a list of empty vars properly).

```
$ limit stacksize 4M
$ (env | wc; getconf ARG_MAX) | awk '
  {env = $1 * 8 + $3; getline; printf "%d\n", ($0 - env) / 9 - 4096}'
111991
$ xargs --show-limits < /dev/null |& grep actually
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 1039698
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
$ yes '""' | xargs  | head -1 | wc -c
65193
$ yes '""' | xargs -s 111991 | head -1 | wc -c
111986
```

Comment: I wrote a **C** program (№ 5 in my question), which should calculate all bytes passed to `execve`, but some bytes are left uncounted. After testing I see that number of uncounted bytes are increasing with the size of filename increasing: **1 byte filenames** - 1130 bytes left "unused"; **2 bytes filenames** - 1708 bytes left; **3 bytes filenames** - 3327 bytes left; **10 bytes filenames** - 3869, etc.

Comment: Correction: not increasing, but fluctuating - **16 bytes filenames** - 873 bytes; **21 bytes filenames** (61886 filenames in total) - 177 bytes only; **31 bytes filenames** - 2377 bytes. I can't see logic behind this behavior.

Comment: @MiniMax see edit. You'll find many Q&As on the subject of ARG_MAX here with more details if need be.

Answer (score 28):

Let xargs do the calculation for you.

```
printf '%s\0' files/* | xargs -0 mv -t new_files_dir
```

Comment: I don't know how I have missed the point of "`xargs` adjusts the argument's size by himself" :(. Seems I have tried and it wasn't work... May be, I thought it wouldn't work, so I didn't try simple `xargs mv -t "new_files_dir"`. Now, I have changed the line of my code to `seq -f "files/%.f${suffix}" "$from" "$to" | xargs mv -t "new_files_dir"` and it works as I want. This is ridiculous :))) P.S. But what entities/values contributes to the argument's size is interesting anyway.

Comment: @MiniMax If you found the answer useful, don't forget to accept ;)

Comment: @AdminBee It is useful, but don't answer to the question, so +1 only :).

Comment: @MiniMax True. I mentioned it because your question might be considered as manifestation of the [X-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in which case this would be a solution to the underlying problem even though it doesn't answer the question asked "literally".

Comment: Others should not search for the solution explanation. Here it is (POSIX https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html): The generated command line length shall be the sum of the size in bytes of the utility name and each argument treated as strings, including a null byte terminator for each of these strings. The xargs utility shall limit the command line length such that when the command line is invoked, the combined argument and environment lists (see the exec family of functions in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017) shall not exceed {ARG_MAX}-2048 bytes.

Comment: Doesn't this just move the problem from `mv` to `printf`? Or is that unlimited because it's a built-in command?

Comment: @Barmar A built-in `printf` does not have the same issue with `*`. However, there _are_ shells with which `printf` is _not_ a built-in. The `sh` and `ksh` shells of OpenBSD, for example.

Answer (score 8):

Your question seems to assume that there's an actual "limit of number of arguments", while in fact it's a combination of two limits:

1. the sum of the string lengths of the command line arguments *and* environment variables including their terminating NUL bytes.
2. the maximum string length of a single command-line argument.

For instance, you may be able to call a command with 200000 single-letter arguments, with 100000 two-letter arguments, but not with a single argument of more than 128k bytes.

Assuming the `xargs` from GNU coreutils, `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` will show what those limits are on your system.

On any system, `xargs` will **not** use the maximum limits of your system when constructing command lines, but will pick something reasonable (it would make no sense whatsoever to put strain on the system in that way).

Answer (score 3):

If it really matters, you could write your very own `batch-move` program in C, which takes e.g. the file list as standard input and does the moving using the relevant Unix system calls.

If not, the "find out the limits and work up to that" is *exactly* what `xargs(1)` (GNU version on Linux, here) does. I doubt it very much that you'll get much faster.

Comment: Yes, I can write a program in another language, Python for example. This question is interesting for educational purposes, not for a real problem.